# Filtering CSV layer attribute table in QGIS Print Composer?

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, layouts, relates

I have a Map content with attribute table and a related attribute csv table, linked with a common field.

When preparing a printing table I'd like to add both tables to my layout, filtering them with map content. For shapefile attribute table, it is pretty easy (checking"Show only visible feature" command). 
I cannot filter related table, because if I check "Show only visible feature", I obtain an empty table. 
Using "Relation children" option, I cannot see any relation, both with table used as children than as parent.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If I understand it well, this is normal behaviour, because your csv table doesn't have a geometry.

1. join layers via **Joins** in vector layer properties.
2. go to print composer and add attribute table of vector layer (with joined csv) twice.
3. hitting *Attribute..* button (in table item properties) you can select individual attributes that will show up - so in one table you can leave only original attributes of vector layer and in second only joined attributes from csv.